# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left (1-n\sin \frac{1}{n}\right)^\alpha$ for parameter $\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

For exactly which real values of $\alpha$ is the series

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-n\sin \frac{1}{n}\right)^\alpha$$

convergent?

Please give some hints.

Comment: Try cocient criterium. Sorry for bad english hope you understand

Comment: Here is a hint: $\sin x \approx x - \frac{x^3}{6} + O(x^5)$ for small $x$. Now work out what this means for $1 - n \sin \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\bigg(1-x~\sin\frac1x\bigg)~dx ~=~ \frac\pi4~.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will use Gauss's test for convergence.  Let $a_n$ be the sequence

$$a_n=1-n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Then, we can expand the sine function is a series of $1/n$ and write the sequence of interest as

$$a_n=  \frac{1}{6n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Then, to proceed with Gauss's test we form the ratio $a_n/a_{n+1}$ and find

$$\begin{align}
\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}&=\frac{\frac{1}{6n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)}{\frac{1}{6(n+1)^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)}\\\\
&=1+\frac{2}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Thus, for the series of interest, $\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n^{\alpha}$, application of Gauss's test reveals that

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right)^{\alpha}&=1+\frac{2\alpha}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

and the series converges when $\alpha >1/2$ and diverges otherwise.

Comment: Then the answer should be $\alpha \geq 1$, right?

Comment: I provided the full "solution" using Gauss's test.  The series converges for any $\alpha>1/2$ , and diverges for all $\alpha\le 1/2$

Comment: Thanks a lot.....:)

Comment: @radha  You're welcome!  My pleasure.